# Why cover a pepper after blackening?

Tags: vegetables, roasting, cooking-myth

I have seen multiple recipes that ask to cover the pepper after blackening? 
What is the use for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It causes the pepper to steam a bit, making it easier to remove the charred skin.

(resting might also be a factor ... I've never done a side-by-side comparison of covered vs. uncovered)

Comment: I haven't done side by side, but I've done a lot both ways, covered and uncovered, so I'm pretty sure covering helps.

Answer (score 1):

The pepper will sweat and soften the skin,  making it easier to remove.   I am a qualified cook but i still think the best way to make pimento is to deep fry the capsicum as the skin burns v before the flesh over cooks,   making for firmer and fresher tasting pimento.   That means you have more opportunity to cook it further in another dish before it turns to mush.